# How can I display a Warning to remove a live USB stick during Shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, xubuntu, overlayfs

When shutting down Xubuntu 20.04 living on a live USB stick with persistence, i.e.

- there is no *file* `\casper-rw`
- but there are ext4-partitions (without journalling) with name `casper-rw` as an overlay to the root file system on the stick and and a partition  `home-rw` separate from the partition from the root partition, from which the stick boots, which is automatically mounted as `/home` in the live system,
- and in the *.cfg files the lines with `initrd=...` in them end with `--- persistent`,

**immediately after confirming the desire to really shut down, the screen turns black.** Only a tiny cursor remains in the upper left corner of the screen. *This black phase can last for longer than one minute!* Only after this black phase, the usual farewell screen of Xubuntu shows up with a turning activity indicator.

I have observed that the black phase can take more than one minute! If you unplug the thumbdrive during the black phase, the partition `casper-rw` will be ruined. Apparently updating the overlay file system on `casper-rw` happens during the black phase.

I want to either see what is happening during the black phase, e.g. see messages running on an perhaps not shown terminal screen, or prevent the screen turning black and show a warning on it to unplug the stick no earlier than when there is a message «Please unplug the installation medium now. Then press Enter.»

1. If there are some terminal actions running in the background, **how could I make those actions visible instead of the black screen**.
2. If 1. is impossible: **How could I show some alternative (e.g. a png-picture with a warning) until the Xubuntu farewell-thing takes the space?**

The bad thing of the current situation is  that you don't see running file system activity, since it is an USB device rather than the HDD or SSD and most USB-sticks no longer have an LED showing access to them. Since the black phase can take that long, the danger of unplugging the stick before the completion of shutdown is too high!

Comment: So.. your problem would go away if you just made sure the shutdown process is finished within a second (*as should be achievable with reasonably modern hardware*)? Possibly the only change you have to do is sacrifice system logs during shutdown instead of waiting for those to be written to a slow disk.